# selecting from three tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a private message system and i have **3 tables** that looks like this

> **CONVERSATIONS**                      conversation_id |
>   conversation_subject
>
> **CONVERSATIONS_MEMBERS**
>   conversation_id|user_id|conversation_last_view|conversation_deleted
>
> **CONVERSATIONS_MESSAGES**
>   message_id|conversation_id|user_id|message_date|message_text

The table structure is  self explanatory. But what i want is to join all the tables , select and show the messages on the inbox page.

I have tried this query but i keep getting errors. I am a novice at sql ; i can only do the simple stuff.

```
   $this->db->select('conversations, conversation_id,conversations, conversation_subject');
 $this->db->select_max('conversations_messages.message_date', 'conversation_last_reply');
 $this->db->from('conversations');
 $this->db->join('conversations_messages','conversations.id=conversations_messages.conversation_id','left');
 $this->db->join('conversations_members','conversations.id= conversations_members.conversation_id','inner');
 $this->db->where('conversations_members.user_id',$sender_id);
 $this->db->where('conversations_members.conversation_deleted','0');
 $this->db->group_by('conversations.conversation_id');
 $this->db->order_by('conversation_last_reply');
 // Get the results from db
 $query = $this->db->get();
 // Result array contains the records selected
 $result_array = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: $this->db->select(); try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your select method. Issue is that you are using 
(,) for binding it should be use with (.)

**Modified query:**

```
$this->db->select('conversations.conversation_id,conversations.conversation_subject');
```

What I have changed:

**Replace this:**

```
'conversations, conversation_id'
```

**With:**

```
'conversations.conversation_id'
```

Comment: i found that out earlier. you also didnt spot a few mistakes below... but i am going to give this to you! thanks